# Why we can't set default value of datetime parameter in stored procedure = getDate()?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to know why I can't set default value to SP datetime parameter to getdate() as below :

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPILog]
(
    @UserID bigint,
    @ActionID smallint,
    @Details nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @Created datetime = getdate()
)
```

if I try to save it will give me a compiler error

```
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UPILog, Line XX
    Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

**EDIT :**
I know that i can do it like below

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPILog]
(
    @UserID bigint,
    @ActionID smallint,
    @Details nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @Created datetime = null
)
AS
if @Created is null
    SET @Created=getdate() ...
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use the @Created as a default though, then set null as the default parameter value and set the @Created parameter with getdate() if it comes with null in your sp.

```
    ...
    @CreateDate datetime = null
)
AS
    if @CreateDate is null
        set @CreateDate = getdate()
...
```

EDIT: There is also the documentation explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53832983/197652

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a function call as a default parameter value.

It's easy to work around: set your calling parameter to `getdate()` if not set.

Comment: why i can't use it .. is it won't be easy to sql engine to do ?

Comment: Is there any explanation why it can't accept this  .. or it's a just as SQL SERVER rule that can't call function as a default parameter

Comment: it has to be a constant value.

Comment: @SpaceCracker the reason I believe is that what you'd be doing (if it were to allow you) is to run the getdate() function at the time your code was compiled (keep in mind we're compiling code) and store the result of that one run of getdate() as the default value... something you don't want.  What you want is for it to run the getdate function any time your UPILog function is called, which should/can-only be done in the function body.

Answer (score 4):

```
  ....     
  @CreateDate datetime = null
)
```

And then use COALESCE() like below -

```
COALESCE(@CreateDate, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

in simplest terms it has to be some constant value and GetDate() is a function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a function as a parameter value. What I do is I set the parameter to some out of scope date like '1900-01-01' and then I check for it in the proc. for example:

```
CREATE PROC uspDataCompare  
    @CompareDate    DATE = '1900-01-01'
AS

IF  @CompareDate = '1900-01-01' SET @CompareDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```