# Why can't GETDATE() be used as the default value of a procedure parameter or a value in an EXECUTE statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MySchema.MyProcedure
   @myDateTimeParam DATETIME = GETDATE()
AS
BEGIN
   -- Do something spectacular
END
```

Upon invocation, the parameter declaration fails with the error, "Error converting data type nvarchar to date." This can be worked around by changing the code as follows:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MySchema.MyProcedure
   @myDateTimeParam DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    IF @myDateTimeParam IS NULL
        SET @myDateTimeParam = GETDATE();

   -- Do something spectacular
END
```

However, assume that `@myDateTimeParam` did not have a default value:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MySchema.MyProcedure
   @myDateTimeParam DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
   -- Do something spectacular
END
```

In this case, you cannot simply pass `GETDATE()` as a formal parameter as follows:

```
EXEC MySchema.MyProcedure GETDATE()
```

as this also produces the dreaded "Error converting data type nvarchar to date" error. The only workaround to this is to first declare a variable and then pass the variable:

```
DECLARE @myDateTimeParam DATETIME = GETDATE();
EXEC MySchema.MyProcedure @myDateTimeParam;
```

Why is this? Both the source and target data types are `DATETIME`. In theory, a data type conversion error should not occur when using the result of `GETDATE()` as either the default value of a parameter or the value of a formal parameter.

Is there some technical reason that this does not work? There's nothing in the MSDN documentation that indicates that it should not work.

Comment: What SQL Server version are you targeting ? `CREATE OR ALTER` was added only recently. In any case, default values have to be constants. That's documented clearly in [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: "because you can't" is unfortunately the most satisfying reason as to why you can't use a function call where a parameter is expected, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399104/incorrect-syntax-near-calling-storedproc-with-getdate

Comment: to me it sounds like "because it isn't very good" is an answer

Comment: @Cato expressing a dislike of SQL Server isnt helpful to the OP.

Comment: @Larnu - I didn't say I didn't like SQL server, I'm saying that that part of it looks poorly designed and just a little shoddy.  He's asking 'why'.  It looks to me that the writers of the parser didn't bother implementing the ability to give a function as a parameter, whereas languages like VB.net have thought it through, you could send the result of a function call to even a reference parameter.

Comment: ..additionally it's important to manage a person's expectations of the product.  We're not a 'SQL fan club', we've got to mention any 'below par' features.  I don't work for Microsoft, I'm not selling it to anyone.

Comment: Saying a product isn't very good is expressing dislike. If you had said "MySQL isn't very good", or "Python isn't very good" I would have made the same comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation, [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), under the *default* subheading in the **arguments** section:

> A default value for a parameter. If a default value is defined for a
>   parameter, the procedure can be executed without specifying a value
>   for that parameter. **The default value must be a constant or it can be
>   NULL.** The constant value can be in the form of a wildcard, making it
>   possible to use the LIKE keyword when passing the parameter into the
>   procedure.

Emphasis mine.

`GETDATE()` is not a constant, so cannot be used an a `DEFAULT` value. Hence why you need to use the format below, as then the value of `GETDATE()` is determined at run time:

```
CREATE PROC YourProc @Param date = NULL
AS

    IF @Param IS NULL BEGIN
        SET @Param = GETDATE();
    END;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. That clears up one part of the question. Now I just have to figure out what's going on with `EXECUTE`. :)

Comment: Just found this in the `EXECUTE` documentation: "If you pass a single word that does not begin with @ and that's not enclosed in quotation marks - for example, **if you forget @ on a parameter name - the word is treated as an nvarchar string, in spite of the missing quotation marks**." I guess that explains it.

Comment: Correct, @MikeHofer. So, if you were to do something like `EXEC YourProc GETDATE;` it would be interpreted as `EXEC YourProc N'GETDATE'`;. Adding the brackets then turns it into something like `EXEC YourProc N'GETDATE'();`, which makes no sense to the compiler.

Comment: Huh @Cato? What are is that even in reference to?

Comment: if I send 'GETDate()' to his stored proc as a parameter, I get the different error message.  It doesn't seem to be treating the text as a varchar

Comment: Considering that the parameter in the OP's SP is a `datetime` , @Cato, you will get an error. The **literal string** `'GETdate()'` can't be converted to a `datetime`.

Comment: that's GETdate() in my quotes as in quoting what was sent, not in the actual text of the code.